# How to handle error on File::Slurp read_file properly?

Tags: perl, error-handling, readfile, slurp

I'm using `File::Slurp` `read_file` and `write_file` functions to updated a file content.

Now I'm focusing on add error handling to it. For that I tried doing following methods for file that not actually exist.

1) `read_file($file) or die("file read failed\n");` Not working. Just throwing Status: 500 software error.

2) `try{ my @lines = read_file($file); } catch{ print "file cannot read";};` not working.

3) err_mode just like in `http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/File-Slurp-9999.13/lib/File/Slurp.pm#err_mode`. Not working.

Is it bad idea to use Perl `File::Slurp`?

Comment: You appear to want to send a HTML document to the CGI client on error, but I don't see any attempt at this.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, that's the plan. For now I just trying to catch the error from read_file($file) command.

Comment: So why did you rule out 1)?

Comment: @ikegami: If 1) worked then I can use try/catch and give HTML error report when dies. Its just debugging one

Comment: I asked why do you say it doesn't work. Not sure why you replied what you would do if it worked.

Comment: It didn't work as expected.

Code:
my @lines = read_file("/etc/asterisk/voicemailq.conf") or die("file read failed\n");

output:

Status: 500
Content-type: text/html

<h1>Software error:</h1>
<pre>read_file 'test.pl' - sysopen: No such file or directory at /<path>/test.pl line 15
</pre>
<p>
For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message 
and the time and date of the error.

</p>

Comment: So `read_file` throws an exception on error rather than returning false like 1) expects. So why did you rule out 2) which catches exceptions?

Comment: Well that's a good question. :) gonna try it now. But I was expecting it to pint "file read failed\n" in somewhere. and it confused me.

Comment: Thanks a LOT @ikegami. It worked. you save my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module's documentation seems outdated and doesn't match the behavior (Edit: it's fixed on CPAN, just the version that comes with Fedora still has the inconsistency) . As documented under `err_mode`, the default behavior on error is to call `croak()`, not to return `undef` as mentioned for `read_file()`. So yes, you'd either have to use `err_mode => 'quiet'` to get the return-undef behavior, or use a try/catch block. As you said neither of those worked, what exactly happens? Both of these work fine for me:

`$ perl -MFile::Slurp -MTry::Tiny -e'try { $s=read_file("foo") } catch { die "bummer" };'
bummer at -e line 1.`

`$ perl -MFile::Slurp -e'$s=read_file("foo", err_mode => "quiet") or die "bummer";'
bummer at -e line 1.`